# How to transform dot to comma in an amount table?

Tags: angular

I have a little question, how to replace the "dot" with a "comma", in the quantity field?

[image]

Instead of getting `587.00`, I want to obtain `587,00`.

I have no idea how to convert this?

Here is my code for now:

**HTML**

```
<tr *ngFor="let line of osts">
   ...
   <td scope="row" class="text-end">{{ line.QUANTITY | variableFormatNum: "1.2-2" }}</td>
   ...
</tr>
```

**variable-format-num.pipe.ts**

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'variableFormatNum' })
export class VariableFormatNumPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {
  }

  transform(input: number | string | null | undefined, digitsInfo?: string): string | null {
    return this.decimalPipe.transform(input, digitsInfo);
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `DecimalPipe` which has a `locale` parameter you can use to show a "comma".

Use for example French locale:

```
transform(input: number | string | null | undefined, digitsInfo?: string, locale: string = 'fr-FR'): string | null {
  return this.decimalPipe.transform(input, digitsInfo, locale);
}
```

For more information see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe).

In your case you don't even need a custom pipe, you can simply use the `DecimalPipe` directly:

```
<tr *ngFor="let line of osts">
   ...
   <td scope="row" class="text-end">{{ line.QUANTITY | number:'1.2-2':'fr-FR' }}</td>
   ...
</tr>
```